# TS2322: Type 'Product[] | null' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

Interface:

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  imageURL: string;
}
```

Component:

```
products: Product[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.sendGetRequest().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<Product[]>)=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res.body; // The error is in this place
    })
  }
```

It throws an error when compiling:

```
TS2322: Type 'Product[] | null' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: res is type of product[] but res.body is not. it could be null.

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
res: HttpResponse<Product[]>
```

It means that res if of type Product[]. And then you are assigning

```
this.products = res.body;
```

where products is of type product array and res is of type `Product[]`. Point to note is, Product interface has no body property and hence TS compiler says it can't assign null to products. Try modifying your code like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.sendGetRequest().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res)=> {
      console.log(res);
      this.products = res.body as Product[];
    })
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

`this.products = res?.body;` or `this.products = res.body ? res.body : [];` will simply solve this problem. But better check the API call, actually why it is sending null as `res.body`? shouldn't it be an empty array instead?